# How to assign tensor value in to another function's tensor variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, variable-assignment

I am calculating some features from a set of data. I made as function for each calculation. I want to put all of those values in an array in another function and I want to call the function. how to do it ?

The 3 functions that I have are

```
def peak_value(x):
    return tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(x))
def rootms(x):
    return tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(x)))
def meanofabs(x):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(x))
```

I want these values to be assigned to a array inside function

```
def pooldata(x,size):
    pool = tf.zeros([1,size],tf.float32)
    # i want to 
    # assign pool[0] with peak_value(x)
    # assign pool[1] with rootms(x)
    # assign pool[2] with meanofabs(x)
    return pool
```

then I want to call the function

```
# define x, size
model = tf.intialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(model)
print(sess.run(pooldata)) # print all the three values
```

How can i do it ?

I tried

```
tf.assign(pool[0],peak_value(x))
```

but it gives me error

```
TypeError: Input 'ref' of 'Assign' Op requires l-value input
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`tf.assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/variable_helper_functions#assign) only lets you assign a value to the entire variable, and not to a slice of a variable. You would have to use [`tf.scatter_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/sparse_variable_updates#scatter_update) to assign to a slice of a variable. However, in your case, you can simply create the `pool` tensor by concatenating the three values. Here is the complete working program :

```
import tensorflow as tf

def peak_value(x):
    return tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(x))
def rootms(x):
    return tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(x)))
def meanofabs(x):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(x))


def pooldata(x,size):
    pool = tf.concat_v2([tf.expand_dims(peak_value(x), 0),
                         tf.expand_dims(rootms(x), 0),
                         tf.expand_dims(meanofabs(x), 0)], axis=0)
    # i want to
    # assign pool[0] with peak_value(x)
    # assign pool[1] with rootms(x)
    # assign pool[2] with meanofabs(x)
    return pool

sess = tf.Session()
size = 1
x = [1.0]

print(sess.run(pooldata(x, size)))
```